# Notifying the Websocket when no message received in PUBSUB

Tags: java, spring-boot, redis, publish-subscribe, message-listener

Below is my Message Listener which listens to Redis PUBSUB. It is working fine. I have to implement a feature in such a way that if no messages are received after threshold/specified time, then I have to send a proper message to websocket(subscription URL same as PUBSUB channel). I don't see any way to that as there will be many clients which subscribes to different channels at different times.

Any help or suggestion would be appreciable.

```
public class PubSubListener implements MessageListener {        
    @Autowired
    private SimpMessagingTemplate simpMessagingTemplate ;   

    @Override
    public void onMessage(Message message, byte[] pattern) {
        logger.info(" MESSAGE RECEIVED FROM PUBSUB ");
        simpMessagingTemplate.convertAndSend(new String(pattern), message.toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Not this way. Use `MessageConsumer.receive(long timeout)`.

Comment: can you please provide a sample code